# ListView with a gridView within infinite height

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-gridview

This is one of the implementations that I have the most difficulty in actually finding the best way to solve.
There are a lot of techniques and ways, but the last answers I found did not really seem to me to solve the problem. Another point is that they are usually very old techniques and libraries.

What I want to do is this:

[image]

How do I create this `ListView` with a `GridView` inside and the screen has infinite height without using ScrollView, so we know that it is not recommended to use `ListView` within `ScrollView`.

I am not asking you to develop the code, but rather recommend me the correct architecture that I should use to implement this (`ScrollView`, `ListView`, `GridView`), or memo a library that has new development concepts that can help me.

**This question arises because many of the existing responses are too old and have outdated ideas.**

I know the question is of a slightly higher level of complexity, but I accept everyone's help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: A single `RecyclerView` can do this.  You'd need a `GridLayoutManager` and a separate `ItemsViewHolder` & `HeaderViewHolder`

Comment: Your `Adapter` views hold the `GridView` as well as headers. And you alternate "headers" and "grids" simply checking if the position is even. Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to solve this using a `RecyclerView`.
The documentation is pretty clear and explains all the details necessary for the development of the functionality.

I will leave the necessary documentation links to implement:

- [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)
- [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html)
- [ItemsViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)

We know that it is always better to use native components in the development, I recommend, but if you prefer to use a library ready to solve your problem, here are some interesting:

- [Sticky Headers](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview)
- [recyclerview-stickyheaders](https://github.com/eowise/recyclerview-stickyheaders)
- [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)